# laravel sub-domain level 0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

i'm trying to create a subdomain in my laravel project ,
i enabled httpd-vhosts.conf and here is the code inside ->

[image]

and here is my host file

[image]

and here is my route.php

[image]

it return check your connection , 
is there any step that i forgot about.

Answer (score 0):

Set vhost like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mysite/public"
    ServerName mysite.dev
    ServerAlias www.mysite
    ErrorLog "logs/mysite-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mysite-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/mysite/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
127.0.0.1   mysite.dev
```

And restart your server...

Set your route

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

HomeController.php

```
public function index()
{
  return view('welcome');
}
```

Comment: Now I m edited my ans, Plz check and tell your errors